# R XLConnect - filtering columns based on column color

Tags: r, excel, xlconnect

In the `XLconnect` package (or any other package in `R`), is it possible to read an `Excel` sheet with colors in their `headers` and filtering them in `R` based on those colors?

For example is `column headers` for `A, C & E` are filled with green, and after being read in R, is it possible to filter them based on that color?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes i believe it is:
Read to `R`, using `xlsx` package and extract:

```
library(xlsx)
wb     <- loadWorkbook("test.xlsx")
sheet1 <- getSheets(wb)[[1]]
```

than get the rows and cells:

```
# get all rows
rows  <- getRows(sheet1)
cells <- getCells(rows)
# quick look at the values
sapply(cells, getCellValue)
#  1.1  2.1  3.1  4.1  5.1  6.1  7.1  8.1  9.1 10.1 11.1 
#  "x"  "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "7"  "8"  "9" "10"
```

now where is the color info? It is in the `cell style`:

```
styles <- sapply(cells, getCellStyle)
```

now a function to give you the cells `RGB` value:

NOTE: the following line give the cells background color `style$getFillForegroundXSSFColor()`

```
cellColor <- function(style) {
    fg  <- style$getFillForegroundXSSFColor()
    rgb <- tryCatch(fg$getRgb(), error = function(e) NULL)
    rgb <- paste(rgb, collapse = "")
    return(rgb)
}
```

want more info? go [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/when-life-gives-you-coloured-cells-make-categories/)

Comment: AWESOME is my response!

Comment: no problem :-) please do not forget to pick as an answer :-D

Comment: unfortunately my reputation is less than 15! really sorry

Comment: just kidding, no worries glad to help :-)

Comment: Incorrect @user1703914. Since this is your post though you cannot upvote any answer, you can [select any answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) that was most helpful to you (click gray tick mark to side).

Comment: There is a follow up question though :
tt1 <- sapply(cells[1], getCellStyle)
tt1
$`1.1`
[1] "Java-Object{org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCellStyle@3106ad8}"
lapply(tt1, cellColor)
$`1.1`
[1] ""
The function cellColor returns nothing even though the actual cell color was filled with "red"